# return the position with specific word

Tags: python, regex

I have a file. It looks like this

```
# AA        : amino acid sequence                                      #
# OBS_sec   : observed secondary structure: H=helix, E=extended        #
#             (sheet), blank=other (loop)                              #
# PROF_sec  : PROF predicted secondary structure: H=helix, E=extended  #
#             (sheet), blank=other (loop)                              #
PHD htm |                  HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH      HHHHHHHHHHHHHH|
PROF_sec |EEEEE     HHHHHHHHHHH   EEEEEE   HHHHHHHHHH    EEEEEEEEE    |
```

I want to know the line which starts with "PROF_sec" then return position of H and E which inside |....|.

I wrote the code like this

```
rexp = re.compile('(?#...)^[PROF_sec][H]+[E]+')
List = [(n.start(0), n.end(0)) for n in rexp.finditer(file)]
```

But it return null value.

How can I modify the code?

PS. All the contents in the file would be consider only in one line. For example, the last "EEEEEEEEE", would give the output (493, 502)

Comment: What you mean by *position of H and E*? What's your expected output?

Comment: How did you come up with that regex ?

Comment: Your best bet is read file line by line and see which line starts with your keyword.

Comment: You could easily use str.startswith

Comment: The output which I want is like this [(446, 451), (470, 476), (493, 502)]) # This is for  E

Comment: And how do you define the position ?

Comment: What do those numbers mean?  Are they character columns?  Line numbers?  Something else?

Comment: All the contents in the file would be consider only in one line. For example, the last "EEEEEEEEE", would give the output (493, 502)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go line by line using *str.startswith* to get the line you want keeping a running total of each line length up to that point then just use a regex to get you H and E substrings:

```
import re

h, e = re.compile("H+"), re.compile("E+")

with open("in.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("PROF_sec"):
            print([(s.start() +sm, s.end()+ sm) for s in h.finditer(line)])
            print([(s.start()+sm, s.end()+sm) for s in e.finditer(line)])
            break
        sm += len(line)
```

Which will give you:

```
[(446, 451), (470, 476), (493, 502)]
[(456, 467), (479, 489)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :D